# Is it possible to enforce bounds on the range/dependent function when using scipy curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a logarithmic function being fit to a set of points

```
def log_func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x) + b
popt, pcov = curve_fit(log_func, x, yn)
```

This results in a plot as follows - [Plotted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7ZN.png)

However, the system has constraints that the range should be fixed between 0 and 100. I've specifically passed points at those bounds (i.e. `x = np.array([3200 ... other points ... 42000 ])` and `y = np.array([0 ... other points ... 100 ] )` but obviously the curve does not necessarily fix those values.

I've read that I can add bounds to the parameters (so `a` and `b` here), but is there a way to constrain the output by specifically forcing the curve through two endpoints. Or alternatively, do I have to introduce some sort of extreme penalization to the function to result in parameters that will be force a result between 0 and 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could formulate the curve fitting problem as a constrained optimization problem and use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to solve it. Considering a data set for which the optimal `a` should be positive, it follows that the requirement on the range of the fitted function is equivalent to the constraints `a*np.log(3200)+b>=0` and `a*np.log(42000)+b<=100`.

One can proceed as follows (I used a simple data set).

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


x = np.array([3200, 14500, 42000])
yn = np.array([0, 78, 100])

def LS_obj(p):
    a, b = p
    return ((log_func(x, a, b) - yn)**2).sum()

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[0] * np.log(3200) + p[1]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: 100 -p[0] * np.log(42000) - p[1]})

p0 = [10,-100] #initial estimate 
sol = minimize(LS_obj,p0 ,constraints=cons)
print(sol.x)  #optimal parameters
```

> `[  36.1955 -285.316 ]`

The following figure compares the `curve_fit` and `minimize` solutions. As expected, the `minimize` solution is within the required range.

[image]